# Решить нелинейное уравнение методом хорд

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы

Есть уравнение x^2 = sin(x). Нужно написать программу,которая находит корни на указанном промежутке. Использовать нужно эту формулу -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код

```
    float e = 0.0001;// погрешность
    float x0 = -100, x1 = 100; // начало и конец координат(в конечном варианте вводится пользователем)

        float result = x1;
        float f0,f;
        int iter = 0; // количество итераций
        do {
            f = sqrtf(sinf(result)); 
            f0 = sqrtf(sinf(x0));
            result = result - (f / (f - f0)) * (result - x0);
            iter++;
        } while (fabs(f) > e && iter < 20000);
```

Проблема в том,что промежуток должен задаваться без ограничений,а sin(x) может давать отрицательное число под корнем,что выливается в NaN и неправильный ответ. Можно ли что-то сделать,что бы избежать подобного?

Comment: Откуда тут появился корень?

Comment: @VTT Не очень понял Ваш вопрос. У этого уравнения 2 корня : 0 и 0,8767262.

Comment: я про `sqrtf` и `отрицательное число под корнем`, откуда они вылезли когда в функции есть только возведение в квадрат?

Comment: Ну, если я все правильно понимаю, x^2 = sin(x) можно преобразовать в x = sqrt(sin(x)). Или я где-то ошибся?

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Такое преобразование могло бы иметь какой-то смысл, если бы у вас справа и слева были независимые переменные, то бишь `y ^ 2 = sin( x )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не врубились в главное: это формула для решения уравнения `f(x) = 0`, так что ваша `f(x)` - это `x^2-sin(x)`.

А дальше все просто, по формуле:

```
double f(double x) {
    return x * x - sin(x);
    }

int main() {
    double x0 = 0.0, x = 10;
    double f0 = f(x0);
    double eps = 0.000001;
    int iter = 0;

    for (; abs(f(x)) > eps && iter < 20000; ++iter) {
        double fi = f(x);
        x = x - fi / (fi - f0) * (x - x0);
        }

    cout << x << "   " << f(x) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,но Ваш код возвращает  2,0434... и -2,0434..., хотя у уравнения только 2 возможных корня - 0 и 0,8767. Прошу прощения, если я что-то не так понял и задаю еще один глупый вопрос

Comment: http://ideone.com/pzGk9S - смотрите, этот код возвращает 0. Чтобы получить второй корень, надо задать другие начальные значения - например, как тут: http://ideone.com/qSCoiu Как вы ухитрились получить эти 2 и -2 - выше моего понимания... Посмотрите по укзанным ссылкам.

Comment: Хмм, интересно. Скопировал мой код на этот сайт - ответ правильный, если запускать в VS - не правильный. В моем коде интервал от  0.1 до 10. Буду разбираться,а Вам еще раз спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Я проверял сначала у себя в студии, все работало.